# Can .htaccess be configured to retain the same address on different pages?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Im configuring a desktop and mobile version of my site and was looking to use js to test for browser dimensions and then load the relevant version, however the problem is if someone shares a link from the mobile version and sends it to a desktop user then they circumvented the check. Is there a way to configure .htaccess (or some other method) to have the address bar show 'mysite.com' even though i would be loading 'mysite.com/mobile.htm'? I know i can always use media queries but that has the downfall of loading unused assets, so this method would be alot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a rewrite instead of a redirect.  With a redirect, the browser is instructed to go to another address. With a URL rewrite, the server just responds with the contents of a different URL.

For just this page it will be simple, but it could be complicated, based on your site.

Another way is to include a little JS in every page to make sure you are on the right one for the device and redirect to the other if not.  It would help if there was some pattern to easily determine the corresponding page.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into rewrites, im not too familiar with .htaccess yet. The last option occurred to me too, and would probably be the best solution if rewrites dont work. The last thing i want to do is have everything all on one page and have to use js exclusion tests to only run certain scripts, bound to be a nightmare when it comes to dom events and triggering scripts.

Comment: Also, be careful that you serve the right version to search engines. You can't count on them to run JS code -- your home page could look blank to them.

Comment: Dont i just log into my google account and submit the page i want indexed? Or will it only take the root .com address and not any specific page?                                                                                                                                   Hmm...maybe i'll just set my main page to be the desktop version with js to route to my mobile version so worst case scenario my HQ page is visible.

Comment: If you have a sitemap, and it includes these pages, they will get indexed.  Without it, Google hits the root and starts following links.  It will listen to HTTP 301 and other server redirects, probably META refresh, but I wouldn't count on it running JavaScript.